# Python Flask Mimetype Javascript module : blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)

Tags: javascript, python, flask, module, mime-types

The server seems to be blocking my javascript module import ("cookieJs.mjs") because "of a dissallowed MIME Type ("text/html")"

I tried (First method):

```
<script type="module">

import { setCookie, getCookie } from './cookieJs.mjs'

</script>
```

And i also tried (Second method) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

import { setCookie, getCookie } from './cookieJs.mjs'

</script>
```

The error now is "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module "

I'm using NginX as a reverse proxy : [Tutorial flask uwsgi production](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-6-%E2%80%94-configuring-nginx-to-proxy-requests)

I'll use whatever method works.

Thanks in advance,

Sydney R